# Unity Multiplayer Photon - How to solve grab conflict?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, multiplayer, photon

Does anyone know how to solve it when two players want to grab an object at the same time?

When one player grabs an object from another player's hand, it looks to both players like only they are holding the object when the first player does not let go. Im using Pun2 for Unity for VR.

Comment: if you can detect theres a conflict.. randomly pick 1

Comment: Decide for one: Either first player wins (=> when grab set object to grabbed => If object is already set to grabbed by someone => you can not grab) or last player wins (when grab set object to grabbed => if grabbing already grabbed object force other player to release object and grab)

Answer (score 0):

PUN can solve this by setting a Custom Property (who picked up item X) with a condition. This is called [Check and Swap (CAS)](https://doc.photonengine.com/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state#check_and_swap_for_properties__cas_) and the condition can be used to make sure only the first pick up attempt is successful.
You basically have to set a property "who-holds-object-X". When nobody holds it, the condition for setting is "who-holds-object-X" == 0.